# tensorflow DynamicRnnEstimator - no prefix or suffix

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a dynamic rnn estimator, but can't seem to get the regressor to identify the correct shape of my data.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.learn import DynamicRnnEstimator
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.constants import (
    ProblemType,
)
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.rnn_common import (
    PredictionType,
)
from tensorflow.contrib.layers import real_valued_column

X = np.random.uniform(size=(1000, 10))
M = X.shape[0]
N = X.shape[1]
y = np.random.uniform(size=1000)

seq_feat_cols = [real_valued_column(column_name='X', dimension=N)]
rnn = DynamicRnnEstimator(ProblemType.LINEAR_REGRESSION,
                          PredictionType.SINGLE_VALUE,
                          sequence_feature_columns=seq_feat_cols)

def get_batch():
    period_steps = 20
    start = random.randint(0, (M - 1) - period_steps - 1)
    end = start + period_steps
    x_tf = tf.expand_dims(X[start:end], axis=0)
    return {'X': x_tf}, tf.constant(y[start:end])

rnn.fit(input_fn=get_batch, steps=10)
```

This is yielding:

```
ValueError: Provided a prefix or suffix of None: 1 and None
```

I've tried extending the dimension on both sides of my ndarray to no avail; any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That `ValueError` looks like it's because `num_units` wasn't provided to the constructor of `DynamicRNNEstimator`. Some other issues:

- The `input_fn` you specify will only be run once! So it should build a TensorFlow graph which either iterates over a dataset or has random TensorFlow operations.
- It looks like you have one label per timestep, in which case I think you need `MULTIPLE_VALUE` rather than `SINGLE_VALUE` for the prediction type.
- The Estimator expects a batch dimension (it can be one)

Putting all of that together:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.learn import DynamicRnnEstimator
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.constants import (
    ProblemType,
)
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.rnn_common import (
    PredictionType,
)
from tensorflow.contrib.layers import real_valued_column

X = np.random.uniform(size=(1000, 10))
M = X.shape[0]
N = X.shape[1]
y = np.random.uniform(size=1000)

seq_feat_cols = [real_valued_column('X')]
rnn = DynamicRnnEstimator(ProblemType.LINEAR_REGRESSION,
                          PredictionType.MULTIPLE_VALUE,
                          num_units=5,
                          sequence_feature_columns=seq_feat_cols)

def get_batch():
  period_steps = 20
  start = tf.random_uniform(
      shape=(),
      minval=0,
      maxval=(M - 1) - period_steps - 1,
      dtype=tf.int32)
  end = start + period_steps
  x_sliced = tf.constant(X)[None, start:end, :]
  y_sliced = tf.constant(y)[None, start:end]
  x_sliced.set_shape((1, period_steps, N))
  y_sliced.set_shape((1, period_steps))
  return {'X': x_sliced}, y_sliced

rnn.fit(input_fn=get_batch, steps=10)
```